# Does a country conquer territory FROM another country?

Tags: prepositions

Does a country conquer territory *from* another country or should some other preposition be used? Am I supposed to use some other verb ('win', 'reclaim')?

> The Russian Empire conquered the territory **from** the Ottoman Empire in the late 17th century.

Comment: Yes, _conquered from_ is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as Kate Bunting commented, 'from' is fine.

As for the verbs, 'win' and 'reclaim' do not quite mean the same as 'conquer'.

You may want to consider 'annex'.